# Given a row representing a path, union a total column

Tags: postgresql, union, aggregate-functions

Say I have a table like the following table that represents a path from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5:

```
+------+----+--------+
| from | to | weight |
+------+----+--------+
| a    | b  |      1 |
| b    | c  |      2 |
| c    | d  |      1 |
| d    | e  |      1 |
| e    | f  |      3 |
+------+----+--------+
```

Each row knows where it came from and where it is going

I would like to union a total row that takes the starting name, ending name, and a total weight like so:

```
+------+----+--------+
| from | to | weight |
+------+----+--------+
| a    | f  |      8 |
+------+----+--------+
```

The first table is a result of a CTE expression, and I can easily get the total of the previous query with `SUM`, but I'm unable to get the `LAST_VALUE` to work in a similar way to:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  ...
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total', FIRST_VALUE(from), LAST_VALUE(to), SUM(weight)
FROM cte
```

The `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` functions require `OVER` clauses which seem to add unnecessary complications to what I would expect, so I think I am going the wrong direction with that. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: ```select `total`, min(to) as to, max(from) as from, sum(weight) as weight
from table```?

Comment: @Krishna Actually, I should edit the question to more match the actual use. The `to` and `from` are not numbers, they are strings

Comment: its not immediately clear to me how `to` gets `f` and `from` gets `a` in your updated example output.

Comment: If  name is always ordered like `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`, try `SELECT 'total', FIRST_VALUE(to) over (order by name), LAST_VALUE(from) over (order by name), SUM(weight)
FROM cte`

Comment: @Krishna They are not sortable, they are the result of a recursive function and the order they are returned is the order of the connections in the path.

Comment: one approach I'd take is to have a column (say, n) that keeps increasing with addition of new path (start with n=1 and do n+1 in recursive function). We can then use `first_value/last_value` functions with `order by n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a strange solution that:

1. Selects the first `from` value (partitioned by `TRUE`)
2. Selects the last `to` value (partitioned by `TRUE` again)
3. Cross joins the sum of all weights, limited to `1`

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    ...
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION ALL (
    SELECT FIRST_VALUE(from) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUE), LAST_VALUE(to)  OVER (PARTITION BY TRUE), total
    FROM cte
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(weight) as total
        FROM cte
    ) tmp
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Is it hacky? Yes. Does it work? Also yes. I'm sure there are better solutions, and I would love to hear them.